# Is this wok nonstick?

Tags: wok

I bought was what I thought was a carbon steel wok, but after realizing that it's black color means it isn't a "classic" carbon steel wok, I am trying to find out what it is made out of :)

I am pretty sure that it is this product, which says it is a black oxide coating: https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Fry-Pan-Chinese-Wok_254864972.html

Does this just mean it is preseasoned or is it possible this is Teflon/Xylan or something like that?  Anyway to tell if it has a coating or not?

Comment: If you are sure you want an uncoated carbon steel wok, you can always destroy the coating and season the wok.

Comment: interesting. what would be the best way to destroy it?

Comment: Wet/dry sandpaper. Until you are sure it is NOT a nonstick coating, refrain from using power tools without dust protection, or from trying to use heat to remove it

Comment: Without more info about your wok (e.g. a picture) we'll have to just assume your Alibaba link is correct; if so, then [this](http://www.swdinc.com/blackoxidebasics.html) is probably a good reference.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar wok, I bought at Target. It was described as "seasoned". I thought I was buying a genuinely seasoned wok.

Nope. It was a black coating just like the one you linked to.

It's a non-stick coating. It worked well for a few meals, then it started to peel.

I used a plastic scrubby to clean the sauce that stuck to the pan, and it cut through the coating. From now on, I will not buy anything from Target. Lie to me one, and you are done.

I paid $80 for it a few years ago. $80 would buy a genuinely seasoned wok back then.

Comment: Oh, since writing this, I tried to season it myself. All it did was bring on rust where the coating came off.